# Jquery load does not hit my method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I got this Jquery (thanks user @Saranga) which i supposed to hit my method:

```
$( ".photography-image" ).click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
       $("<div></div>")
           .addClass("dialog")
           .appendTo("body")
           .dialog({
               close: function() { $(this).remove(); },
               modal: true,
               height: 500,
               width: 500
           })
           .load("/Home/EditPhoto?id=" + $(this).data("imgId"));

   });
```

This is the method it is supposed to hit:

```
public ActionResult EditPhoto(string id)
        {
            var photo = RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>(id) as Photography;

            return PartialView("_editPhoto", photo);

        }
```

Here is some of the relevant view:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Photographys)
                        {
                            <li class="span3" style="text-align: center">

                                <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1">

                                    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 10px;">@item.Name</h3>

                                    <div class=""><div class=""><img src="@item.ImgUrl" alt="" class="photography-image" data-imgid="@item.Id" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;"></div></div>

                                </div>

                            </li>
                        }
```

When I put a breakpoint at the method and click the image which should trigger the method nothing happens, any ideas on this?
Thanks!

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{xid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", xid = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: can you add your routing rules from routeconfig?

Comment: You're wrapped this in a $.ready(...) yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `e.preventDefault();`.

You dont have the "e" defined as the event.

As I can see, there is no onclick defined for the elements, remove the `e.preventDefault();`, and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little more background on tracking down these types of issues. There is very little that is more frustrating than when a framework you rely on isn't cooperating with you. Narrowing down the scope of the problem can be extremely helpful toward solving the problem. Here are the steps that I use:

1. Look at your browser's javascript console. Are there any errors that might prevent later code from executing?
2. View the browser activity in its navigation log (I prefer the Webkit debugger - Chrome or Safari). Did the browser actually send a network request?
3. What response did the network request receive?
4. Do the parameter names match between the url in the navigation log and the action method's signature? Do they match an existing route?
5. If so, were there any errors logged on the server?
6. Log your requests using global attributes. See [DebugInfoAttribute](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/global-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) for one way to track what the server is seeing.

   ```
   public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
       var browser = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser;
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response
            .Write(string.Format(_outputFormat,
                 HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"],
                 String.Format("{0}({1})",browser.Browser,browser.Version),
                    filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
                    filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"],
                    _startWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
   }
   ```

In this case, the `e.preventDefault();` would have shown up in the javascript console. As seen by the accepted answer, your problem would have been solved at step one. Using a systematic approach like this can go a long way toward eliminating frustration by giving you a plan of attack. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Pass "e" to the function like this:

$( ".photography-image" ).click(function( **e** ) {